# How can I post more than 20 items?

Tags: php, post, limit

I want to post multiple values:

index.php:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input name='name[]' value='1'/>
<input name='name[]' value='2'/>
<input name='name[]' value='3'/>
<input name='name[]' value='4'/>
<input name='name[]' value='5'/>
<input name='name[]' value='6'/>
<input name='name[]' value='7'/>
<input name='name[]' value='8'/>
<input name='name[]' value='9'/>
<input name='name[]' value='10'/>
<input name='name[]' value='11'/>
<input name='name[]' value='12'/>
<input name='name[]' value='13'/>
<input name='name[]' value='14'/>
<input name='name[]' value='15'/>
<input name='name[]' value='16'/>
<input name='name[]' value='17'/>
<input name='name[]' value='18'/>
<input name='name[]' value='19'/>
<input name='name[]' value='20'/>
</form>
```

update.php

```
if ($_POST['name']) {
    foreach ( $_POST['name'] as $key=>$value ) {
        echo $_POST['name'][$key];
   }
}
```

My problem is that somehow the posting is limited to 20. When I add another input field `<input name='name[]' value='21'/>` then the output is still only 20 items. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server there can be the `max_input_vars` value setted at `20`.

Change that value by creating a `.htaccess` file in the dir where the script run and insert into:

```
php_value max_input_vars 100
```

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars.

Comment: Ok, good idea. I will test it now and let you know if it worked